# Correct preposition before advance payment

Tags: prepositions

Which preposition should i use before payment in sentence below?

> We mostly sell with/for/on advance payment of 50%.

I thought “with” is the best choice but please correct me if it is wrong .

Comment: To *sell [preposition] advance payment* isn't really a natural way of expressing this anyway. I'd suggest *We mostly sell **on the basis of** a 50% advance payment.*

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't say it as any of those. You want to structure the sentence differently.

> We generally require a 50% advance payment on all sales.

This indicates that exceptions are possible (as I assume was the intent in using *mostly*), but it focuses the advance payment, making *require* the principal verb and thus removing the need for a preposition on *advance payment*.

If you're absolutely wedded to your sentence structure, then use *with*, but *generally* is more formal than *mostly* and the sentence structure you've got at the moment isn't natural/idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,*with* is the best choice in this context.But I suggest using *We mostly sell with pre-payment of 50%*. Please refer to [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/pre-payment?q=prepayment)